# index out of range while attempting to write to file

Tags: go, buffer, file-manipulation

I believe the issue is that the buffer isn't getting flushed but am not certain, p

Error

```
bash-4.4$ ./golang-updateprops -f chaosmonkey.config
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.ingest(0x7ffeefbff700, 0x12, 0x0, 0x0)
    #/golang-updateprops/update_properties.go:98 +0xa9d
main.main()
    #/golang-updateprops/update_properties.go:121 +0xb6
```

Code

```
package main

import (
  "strings"
  "bufio"
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
  "flag"
  "os"
  "io"
  "bytes"
)

var (
  filename  string
)

func isCommentOrBlank(line string) bool {
  return strings.HasPrefix(line, "#") || "" == strings.TrimSpace(line)
}

func fileExists(filename string) bool {
  if _, err := os.Stat(filename); err == nil {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

func limitLength(s string, length int) string {
  if len(s) < length {
    return s
  }
  return s[:length]
}

func padWithSpace(str, pad string, length int) string {
    for {
        str += pad
        if len(str) > length {
            return str[0:length]
        }
    }
}

func ingest(filename string) (err error) {
  file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_RDWR, 0666)
  defer file.Close()

  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  reader := bufio.NewReader(file) // Start reading from the file with a reader.

  for {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    var l []byte
    var isPrefix bool

    for {
      l, isPrefix, err = reader.ReadLine()
      buffer.Write(l)

      if !isPrefix { // If we've reached the end of the line or we're at the EOF, break
        break
      }
    }

    if err == io.EOF || err != nil {
      break
    }

    line    := buffer.String()
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`^#([^=]+)=(.+)$`)
    matches := pattern.FindAllStringSubmatch(line, -1) // matches is [][]string

    for _, string := range matches {
      n := strings.TrimSpace(string[1])
      v := strings.TrimSpace(string[2])
      e := strings.ToLower(strings.Replace(n, ".", "/", -1))

      // newline creation for if block
      nl := "{{if exists \"/" + e + "\" -}}\n"
      nl += padWithSpace(n, " ", 80) + " = {{getv \"" + e + "\" \"" + v + "\"}}\n"
      nl += "{{end -}}\n"

      buffer.WriteString(nl)
      file.Sync()
    }

    // dont proccess comments
    if (isCommentOrBlank(line)) {
      buffer.WriteString(line)
      file.Sync()
    } else {
      a := strings.Split(line, "=")
      n := strings.TrimSpace(a[1])
      v := strings.TrimSpace(a[2])
      e := strings.ToLower(strings.Replace(n, ".", "/", -1))

      nl := padWithSpace(n, " ", 80) + " = {{getv \"" + e + "\" \"" + v + "\"}}\n"
      buffer.WriteString(nl)
      file.Sync()
    }
  }

  if err != io.EOF {
    fmt.Printf(" > Failed!: %v\n", err)
  }
  return
}

func main() {
  flag.StringVar(&filename, "f", "filename", "The file location to be parsed")
  flag.Parse()

  if !fileExists(filename) {
    fmt.Println(" > File does not exist\n")
  }

  ingest(filename)
}
```

Config being parsed

```
# The file contains the properties for Chaos Monkey.
# see documentation at:
# https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Configuration

# let chaos run
simianarmy.chaos.enabled = true

# don't allow chaos to kill (ie dryrun mode)
simianarmy.chaos.leashed = true

# set to "false" for Opt-In behavior, "true" for Opt-Out behavior
simianarmy.chaos.ASG.enabled = false

# uncomment this line to use tunable aggression
#simianarmy.client.chaos.class = com.netflix.simianarmy.tunable.TunablyAggressiveChaosMonkey

# default probability for all ASGs
simianarmy.chaos.ASG.probability = 1.0

# increase or decrease the termination limit
simianarmy.chaos.ASG.maxTerminationsPerDay = 1.0

# Strategies
simianarmy.chaos.shutdowninstance.enabled = true
simianarmy.chaos.blockallnetworktraffic.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.burncpu.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.killprocesses.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.nullroute.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.failapi.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.faildns.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.faildynamodb.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.fails3.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.networkcorruption.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.networklatency.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.networkloss.enabled = false

# Force-detaching EBS volumes may cause data loss
simianarmy.chaos.detachvolumes.enabled = false

# FillDisk fills the root disk.
# NOTE: This may incur charges for an EBS root volume.  See burnmoney option.
simianarmy.chaos.burnio.enabled = false
# BurnIO causes disk activity on the root disk.
# NOTE: This may incur charges for an EBS root volume. See burnmoney option.
simianarmy.chaos.filldisk.enabled = false

# Where we know the chaos strategy will incur charges, we won't run it unless burnmoney is true.
simianarmy.chaos.burnmoney = false


# enable a specific ASG
# simianarmy.chaos.ASG.<asgName>.enabled = true
# simianarmy.chaos.ASG.<asgName>.probability = 1.0

# increase or decrease the termination limit for a specific ASG
# simianarmy.chaos.ASG.<asgName>.maxTerminationsPerDay = 1.0

# Enroll in mandatory terminations.  If a group has not had a
# termination within the windowInDays range then it will terminate
# one instance in the group with a 0.5 probability (at some point in
# the next 2 days an instance should be terminated), then
# do nothing again for windowInDays.  This forces "enabled" groups
# that have a probability of 0.0 to have terminations periodically.
simianarmy.chaos.mandatoryTermination.enabled = false
simianarmy.chaos.mandatoryTermination.windowInDays = 32
simianarmy.chaos.mandatoryTermination.defaultProbability = 0.5

# Enable notification for Chaos termination for a specific instance group
# simianarmy.chaos.<groupType>.<groupName>.notification.enabled = true

# Set the destination email the termination notification sent to for a specific instance group
# simianarmy.chaos.<groupType>.<groupName>.ownerEmail = foo@bar.com

# Set the source email that sends the termination notification
# simianarmy.chaos.notification.sourceEmail = foo@bar.com

# Enable notification for Chaos termination for all instance groups
#simianarmy.chaos.notification.global.enabled = true

# Set the destination email the termination notification is sent to for all instance groups
#simianarmy.chaos.notification.global.receiverEmail = foo@bar.com

# Set a prefix applied to the subject of all termination notifications
# Probably want to include a trailing space to separate from start of default text
#simianarmy.chaos.notification.subject.prefix = SubjectPrefix

# Set a suffix applied to the subject of all termination notifications
# Probably want to include an escaped space " \ " to separate from end of default text
#simianarmy.chaos.notification.subject.suffix =  \ SubjectSuffix

# Set a prefix applied to the body of all termination notifications
# Probably want to include a trailing space to separate from start of default text
#simianarmy.chaos.notification.body.prefix = BodyPrefix

# Set a suffix applied to the body of all termination notifications
# Probably want to include an escaped space " \ " to separate from end of default text
#simianarmy.chaos.notification.body.suffix =  \ BodySuffix

# Enable the email subject to be the same as the body, to include terminated instance and group information
#simianarmy.chaos.notification.subject.isBody = true
#set the tag filter on the ASGs to terminate only instances from the ASG with the this tag key and value
#simianarmy.chaos.ASGtag.key = chaos_monkey
#simianarmy.chaos.ASGtag.value = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be coming from these two lines inside your `ingest` function:

```
n := strings.TrimSpace(a[1])
v := strings.TrimSpace(a[2])
```

Should that maybe be `a[0]` and `a[1]`?

Comment: Still not writing to file though, so scratching my head about that guy as well

Comment: @ehime I'd start by capturing the `error` that is returned by `file.Sync()` and seeing if there's anything there. That said, it feels like maybe the implementation here is slightly over-engineered – would it be possible to just mutate a string and then use `ioutil.WriteFile` to spit out the config, rather than using a buffer?

Comment: Most likely but this is also literally the first app i've written in GO ;)

Comment: @ehime I fail to see what file you're trying to *write* — you're only reading one.

Comment: @kostix I'm trying to write back to the same file im reading from

Comment: @kostix I got it figured out it was `file.WriteTo` not `buffers.WriteTo`